# Tapping URL in Safari give the option to open in my iOS app instead

Tags: ios, url, mobile-safari

I am wondering if it is possible for users browsing my website to tap or tap and hold a link, and have the option to open that in my iOS app instead of continuing to use Safari.

E.g. tap http://www.example.com/product123 and have that open my app and show "product123".

This seems different than using custom URL schemes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes you can!** With iOS 9 Apple introduced Universal Link concept through which you can open installed app from weblink or redirect user to appstore

Read the article from below link for more info :
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW1